# Asp.net anchors and regular views on nav cannot communicate

Tags: asp.net, navigation, anchor, smooth-scrolling

Maybe not the best title, but I didn't know how to name it.

Navigation contains:

1. Who are we?
2. What we do?
3. Our team
4. Services
5. Contact

   ```
   <ul class="list-unstyled h-100">
   <li>
       <a href="#who-are-we">Ko smo mi?</a>
   </li>
   <li>
       <a href="#what-we-do">Čime se bavimo?</a>
   </li>
   <li>
       <a href="#our-team">Naš tim</a>
   </li>
   <li>
       <a href="/page/services">Usluge</a>
   </li>
   <li>
       <a href="/page/contact">Kontakt</a>
   </li>
   ```

Numbers 1, 2 and 3 belong to view About, and as you can see, Services and Contact are Separated views.
I have jQuery code that controls smooth scroll between anchors

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (event) {
    if (this.hash !== "") {
        event.preventDefault();

        var hash = this.hash;

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
        }, 600, function () {

            window.location.hash = hash;
        });
    }
});
```

And everything works just fine until user goes to Services or Contact view. After that, he can't come back to any of this anchors, which is normal, because links not pointing to controller. If I put /page/about/ in front of every anchor, then I don't have smooth scroll in about page, it loads every time from beginning.
Question is, is there any solution to solve this, to have anchors in nav and landing page, and other views?

Here is the link to the website, so if you don't understand me, you can try by yourself. Btw, don't click on contact, there is no view for that yet, and services is empty view, so don't be confused with style.
https://test.cherrydevelop.com

P.S. If anyone have better name for topic, you are welcome!

Comment: I think you should put `/page/about` in front of those links. so it would be `/page/about#what-we-do`. Your problem probably has to do with that when you add `/page/about` to the front of your href your jquery selector `a[href^="#"]` breaks because the href no longer **starts with** (^) the hashtag (#). So change the selector to `a[href*="#"]`, which uses * (contains) instead of ^ (starts with). Or just use a class (i.e. `.scroll-link`). You will also have to look for the hash on page load and scroll to it if it exists

Comment: Already tried that...It doesn't work...loads page from begining every time just on anchor...a[href*="#"] in that case don't do the job, because controller page and view about is called every time

Comment: When I put `/page/about` in front of hashes, and set `a[href*="#"]` still cannot access from service page, but I found a solution. When I remove `event.preventDefault();` from my jquery function...then it works...Thanks anyway